# User Authentication about JSON (Android)

Tags: android, json, authentication, httprequest, credentials

I am trying to create an android application where I get JSON Files from web and I am having problem with sending HTTP request with authentication.

Here's corresponding parts of the code :

```
public String getJSON(String address){
    
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(address);
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    try{

        client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope("my URL address here", AuthScope.ANY_PORT), new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
        httpGet.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json");


        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if(statusCode == 200){
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(GetData.class.toString(),"Failed to get JSON object");
        }
    }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

and I call it in my main method as:

```
String readJSON = jsondata.getJSON("my URL");
```

After that, I try to print the String to see what I get from web, and although I put username and password correctly I get the following text on my screen:

{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}

It would be great if anyone can answer my question and explain it.

### Solved. Solution:

I used the code of the below which is written by samsad. And added the following parts :

```
 String credentials = username + ":" + password;
 String credBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT).replace("\n", "");

 httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+credBase64);}
```

Comment: please elaborate the problem which you are having.

Comment: You get 200 status but receive authentication error - i find this a bit problematic. Can you log in with the same credentials through web-browser? You might try to check this [link](http://www.androidsnippets.com/make-http-request-with-credentials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code..

```
public class GetJsonObjectClass {

      /**
     * Gets the JSON objectfrom url.
     *
     * @param url the url
     * @return the JSON objectfrom url
     */
    public  static  JSONObject  getJSONObjectfromURL(String url) 
        {
            InputStream mIs = null;
            String result = "";
            JSONObject jObjectLogin = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                mIs = entity.getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                TCGStaticVariables.errorText = e.toString();
            }

            try{
                BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mIs,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if(line.trim().equals("\n"))
                        continue;
                    stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                mIs.close();
                result=stringBuilder.toString();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }
            try {
                jObjectLogin = new JSONObject(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return jObjectLogin;
        }
}
```

Comment: how will I apply authentication to this code ? I cannot see the username and password parts ?

Comment: If your API made with GET method then you can directly prepare url and call this method: URL ="";JSONObject  jnc = GetJsonObjectClass.getJSONObjectfromURL(URL);

Comment: I tried but I still have the same result. I need to be logged in to get the right JSONObject. In web browser I have the same issue if i am not logged in, but if i log in I can get the right JSONObject.